# Calendar VBA code for selective cells only

Tags: vba

I use the following code with a calendar on a financial spreadsheet in column A only to avoid accidental data entry in columns other than A. I have changed the sheet now to include dates in column "O" so I would like it to include column "A and O" in the code. Would this be possible please?

```
Private Sub Calendar1_Click()
Columnchk = Mid(ActiveCell.Address, 2, 1)
' set value only if active column = A
If Columnchk = "A" Then ActiveCell.Value = Me.Calendar1.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got the question right, the solution is `Or` operator:

```
Private Sub Calendar1_Click()
Columnchk = Mid(ActiveCell.Address, 2, 1)
' set value only if active column = A or O
If Columnchk = "A" Or Columnchk = "O" Then ActiveCell.Value = Me.Calendar1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Also, i think getting active column using `Mid(...)` is not actually good idea. I guess you would rather use `Col = ActiveCell.Column` instead (but it returns integer value so you will need to change your `If` statement to something like `If Col = 1 Or Col = 15 Then ...`).

Comment: @camioneur, if it helped to you please mark it as answer (and maybe vote for it). Thank you.

Comment: I'd be happy to vote if I could find out where/how to do that?

Comment: @camioneur, there are "big zero" with arrows up and down on the left side of my answer. So, up arrow is vote up )